# R: I try to build my own pipeline. How can I paste steps as function?

Tags: r

so I try to build my own pipeline in R that will flow like this

```
steps <- c("encode_label()",
       "standard_scale()")
steps <- noquote(steps)
head(trainSet %>% steps[1])
```

but the output is,

```
> head(trainSet %>% steps[1])
[1] NA NA
```

where,

```
> steps[1]
[1] encode_label()
```

it is different with,

```
> head(trainSet %>% encode_label(), 2) 
X mpg cylinders displacement horsepower weight acceleration model.year origin car_name
2 4  16         8          304        150   3433         12.0         70      1       11
3 5  17         8          302        140   3449         10.5         70      1      128
```

Answer (score 2):

You could define the steps by starting a magrittr pipe sequence with a `.`:

```r
library(magrittr)

steps <- . %>%
  mean() %>%
  format(nsmall = 3)

steps
#> Functional sequence with the following components:
#> 
#>  1. mean(.)
#>  2. format(., nsmall = 3)
#> 
#> Use 'functions' to extract the individual functions.
```

And then the application:

```r
# All at once
1:5 %>% steps()
#> [1] "3.000"

# One-by-one
1:5 %>% steps[[1]]() %>% steps[[2]]()
#> [1] "3.000"
```

If you want to keep the interface of specifying the steps as a character
vector, I think you’d need to delve into some more advanced metaprogramming
to make that work.